# Can children die?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A dwarf was digging out a magma channel under my thriving fortress , when he stumbled upon an adamantine vein. Praise the miners! Unfortunately, I was invaded shortly after.

Long story short, the only survivor except for a caged peahen is a Dwarven child who has been battling a Steam Demon and a Falcon Monster for *weeks*. She's become a legendary armor user, fighter, dodger and observer, but is unconscious, exhausted, winded, pale, hungry, dehydrated and very unhappy. She's also constantly throwing a tantrum.

Will she ever die, or do I have to abandon the fortress?

> Monom órnish has been very unhappy lately. She was forced to endure the decay of a father. She has lost a father to tragedy recently. She has complained of thirst lately. She has lost a mother to tragedy recently. She was comforted by a lovely waterfall lately. She admired a fine Seat lately. She choked on smoke underground lately. She has been attacked lately. She sustained major injuries recently. She was caught in a snow storm recently. She was caught in freakish weather recently.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InfantImmortality

Comment: Get runesmith and change the dwarf to happy and destroy the creatures from hell!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, children can die from any method just like any other dwarf. You can't control children at all, but unless it a baby, which this doesn't seem to be, they will feed themselves and work farms. She'll mature if she lives to be thirteen years old, and migrants will still come, so this fort may have some hope!

Comment: Actually, migrants just arrived. That girl kept the fortress alive for six months! Unfortunately a forgotten beast just arrived, too -- I'll see if the migrants are quick enough to wall themselves into the wine cellar. What I'm actually asking is this: the kid has been fighting demons without eating or drinking for six months. Is it a bug? Won't she starve until she turns 13 years old?

Comment: @Mark She can starve before she turns 13. In the meantime, she's just one totally badass Dwarfette. You should build a shrine to her. It's the DF thing to do.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, children can still starve to death...I'm not sure why she hasn't...

Comment: Probably a bug, stranger things have happened with children and adults alike. Still, if she recovers she will be an epic military leader.

Comment: Uhmmm... sounds like a nice game... I'll see if I can try it sometimes soon...

Comment: @Yaztromo: ha ha, you should read some of the other questions. :P It is a really, really good game though.

Comment: One year later, all the immigrants are dead and the child is carrying on. I'll abandon the fortress here.